# Salvar texto no visual

Tags: c#, fila

Estou tentando criar um diário que tem uma classe lembrete para adicionar só o lembrete fora do diário.

Bom pessoal to com um problema aqui na escola e queria saber  uma coisa, como fazer com que o texto que eu escrevi fique salvo, mesmo depois de fechar o console aquele texto fique lá.

Obs: tenho que usar fila, não estou usando forms e tem que estar orientado a objeto. Se quiserem pra entender melhor coloco o código aqui.

CÓDIGO DA CLASSE LEMBRETE:

private String anotar;
        private String data;
        private String importancia;

```
    public Lembrete(String anotarx, String datax)
    {
        anotar = anotarx;
        data = datax;
        importancia = Importancias.RAZOAVEL;
    }

    public String Anotar
    {
        get
        {

            return anotar;
        }
        set
        {

            anotar = value;

        }
    }

    public String Data
    {
        get
        {
            return data;
        }
        set
        {
            data = value;

        }
    }

    public String Importancia
    {
        get
        {

            return importancia;
        }
        set
        {

            importancia = value;

        }
    }

    public String RetornarLembrete()
    {

        String texto = "";

        texto = anotar + "" + data;
        return texto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Acho melhor coloca o código para ajudar a entender o problema, vc quer salvar o arquivo mesmo que o programa esteja fechado ? se salvar em um txt ajuda ?

Comment: Salvar o texto seria para exibir, consultar? Salvará apenas um texto ou vários?

Comment: Quero que quando o usuário digite algo no lembrete, o que ele digitou salve automaticamente quando ele fechar e quando ele abrir novamente, o texto que ele digitou antes ainda continue lá.

Comment: exibir, consultar e se o usuário quiser editar. Ta meio complicado pra mim pois ainda estou aprendendo isso :p